# FastAPI: File upload timeout

Tags: python, file, nginx, upload, fastapi

I have a FastAPI function that receives file,  saves it locally, untars it, pushes the untarred image into an artifactory location. For some reason, the larger files or at times smaller files gets timed out while uploading with 200 response. I seem to follow all the suggestions like nginx as well but no luck!

```
 @router.post("/upload_container")
async def post_container(file: UploadFile = File(), new_container_image: str = Form(), new_tag: str = Form()):
    if file.content_type != "application/x-tar":
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Can only accept tarred version of Docker file")
    file_path = str(str(uuid.uuid4()).split("-")[1]) + ".tar"
    async with aiofiles.open(file_path, "wb") as out_file:
        while content := await file.read(1024):  # async read chunk
            await out_file.write(content)  # async write chunk
    file_path = str(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), file_path)))
    command = "podman load --input {}".format(file_path)
    result = subprocess.run(split(command), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        return {"filename": file.filename, "details": result.stderr, "Error": {" failed to unwrap"}}
    tagged_image = str(str(result.stdout).split("\n")[0]).split("Loaded image(s):")[1]
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)
    if tagandpull(tagged_image, new_container_image, new_tag) != True:
        return {"message": "Unable to push the image", "image_name": f"{file.filename}"}
    return {
        "filename": file.filename,
        "Details": {
            "new_url": "artifactorylocation.cloud.com/"
            + config_data.output["repos"]["local"]["deploy_repo"]
            + "/"
            + new_container_image,
            "new_tag": new_tag,
        },
    }
```

Here is my nginx annotation.

```
  annotations: {
    'kubernetes.io/ingress.class': 'nginx',
    'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size': '2400m',
    'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout': '600',
    'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout': '600',
    'nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout': '600'
  },
```

Has anyone faced this issue?